# What does "ColorEngine" software do on Samsung laptops?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bloatware

I bought a new Samsung laptop. When I booted the first time, I noticed that it had a lot of pre-installed stuff. I removed what seemed to be disposable.

However, when I use something like Geek Uninstaller, it shows a software called ColorEngine. Searching it on Google showed that it is a software from Samsung but little information about what it does and if it can be removed. It does not appear on Start Menu when searching. It seems to run at startup but doesn't consume much memory.

What does it do? It can be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Google-foo is strong today - see [this](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/which-bloatware-should-i-remove-625884/) link which states "ColorEngine from memory is a dynamic color profile changer" - this means that you can get rid of it, but it might slightly change the way your screen looks - ie the colors will be balanced a different way.

Comment: I actually found that link (not in my first search) but I skimmed the text. Silly me :(

Comment: Since it doesn't seems to be harmful I'm gonna leave there.